# Rails 4 Heroku postgreSQL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm having trouble changing an existing app with SQLite3 to postgreSQL. I'm following this tutorial to convert SQLite3 to postgreSQL and deploy it to heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres.

I removed gem 'sqlite3' and replaced with gem 'pg'. 
After modifying config/database.yml, I ran migration.

`$rake db:create` and `$rake db:migrate` resulted this error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Gemfile used in production:

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
```

Following is the errors I get when I run with the local server:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Read the error message. Did you check the things it's telling you to check? Did you search for the error message? I'll bet you're probably on a Mac, too, in which case add "OS X" to that search, because it's a v.common issue for Mac users of PostgreSQL + Rails. Hard to help more because *you didn't include your PostgreSQL version or how you installed PostgreSQL, or your OS and version*.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have not added a Heroku Postgres database to your Heroku account.  When a database is configured, your application will connect to it.  Without a database configured, it's falling back to looking for one locally.

If you do have a database configured, something is wrong with your Heroku environment preventing your database connection settings from being found.